# What is a set of generators for $PSL(2,p)$ for $p$ prime?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, finite-fields, projective-geometry

What is a set of generators for $PSL(2,p)$ when $p$ is prime, in particular when $p$ is a Mersenne prime? I know that for $p=7=2^3-1$, we can view $PSL(2,7)$ as the group of linear fractional transformations and the generators are $k\mapsto -1/k$, $k\mapsto k+1$, and $k\mapsto 2k$. This works because the quadratic residues modulo 7 are powers of 2, $\{1,2,4\}$. How does this generalize, for example to $p=31$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any $SL(2,p)$ is a quotient of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ under obvious coefficient reduction. (While it seems "obvious", this is a theorem and not entirely trivial. It also holds for larger dimensions.)

This means that for any prime $p$ you can just take the two generators $k\mapsto -1/k$ and $k\mapsto k+1$ for $PSL(2,p)$, regardless of quadratic residues.

Comment: Okay, so I'm reading this as reflections and translations are sufficient to generate $PSL(2,\mathbb{F}_p)$. Is it obvious what happens for $PSL(2,\mathbb{F}_q)$ where $q=p^n$? What I am seeking is an isomorphism of symmetry groups between $PGL(n,\mathbb{F}_2)$ and $PSL(2,\mathbb{F}_p)$ when $2^n=p+1$, a generalization of the $n=3$ case. This may be obviously ruled out due to the groups having different orders; I haven't checked.

Comment: $PGL(n,2)=PSL(n,2)$ cannot be isomorphic to $PSL(2,p)$ (except the obvious $n=2=p$ and $n=3$, $p=7$).

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I’ll add a line in sage at https://GitHub.com/jacksonwalters/fano-plane-symmetries